# Enforcing XML style checking with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, checkstyle

I saw https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/xmlstyle.html. It looks like Google can do xml checking. How do they do that? I know that checkstyle plugin in Gradle only checks for Java style.

Answer (score 1):

[PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) does style checks for XML, and there is a [gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html). Haven't actually used it myself though.